# Google Lighthouse offscreen images & SEO

Tags: seo, lazyloading

I've used Google Lighthouse for the first time and my main problem are offscreen images, meaning I should lazy load. I already do that but I have and script preventing bots to lazy load, so they get the whole content.

I want to:

- lazy load images
- get them indexed in google images
- rank good at lighthouse (to focus on other issues and also I guess it would affect my score)

Most articles I've seen are at least 2 years old and I don't get what should I do. Should I stop blocking bots to lazy load?

Comment: Sorry but this question appears to be asked in various forms already on Pro Webmasters, the fact that you are using Google's lighthouse does not make the question unique, since this is merely a testing tool. The real question is how to use Lazy Load and rank images on Google images, which has been asked before. It should also be noted that there is little evidence to support that improving scores in Google Insights, Google Lighthouse, Pingdom, WebPageTest, gtmetrix have little to no influence in terms of rankings, since Google ranks speed by 'actual' speed, not score...

Comment: Sadly, while Google likes to spoon feed webmasters with content is king, and experience is king, the sad reality is that 'currently' there is absolutely no evidence to support that Google's bot understands what a good experience actually is and doesn't reward for it, all evidence points to external signals. However I do recommend GH for improving user experience because that can lead to people wanting to link to you.

Comment: Thanks for you tips. Could you point what GH is? And also, you say that Lazy load and Google images has been asked a lot but, are there any answers to that? I could start pulling a thread

Comment: I've added some more similar questions at the top, including one for other search engines. Also, many other similar questions here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=Lazy+load+is%3Aquestion